# using flask-migration with flask-appbuilder

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate, flask-appbuilder

I have a `flask-appbuilder` (FAB) project and I would like to use `flask-migrate` to handle db migrations. However FAB creates the db on its own beforehand, so that `flask-migrate` cannot compute the migrations

I'm aware of [this example](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/tree/master/examples/quickmigrate) and of [this issue on FAB's repository](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/738), however I wasn't able to use them to solve the problem.

This is a minimal app to show the problem.

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_appbuilder import AppBuilder, SQLA
from flask_migrate import Migrate
import os
from flask_appbuilder import Model
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer


class Config():
    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


db = SQLA()
migrate = Migrate()
appbuilder = AppBuilder()


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    with app.app_context():
        appbuilder.init_app(app, db.session)
        appbuilder.post_init()

    return app


class MyTable(Model):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    mycol = Column(Integer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

It can be tested in a virtual environment with the following `requirements.txt`:

```
flask-appbuilder==3.1.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.24
flask-migrate
```

By issuing

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
flask db init
flask db migrate
```

the output reads `INFO [alembic.env] No changes in schema detected`, so no migration. However the db has been created.

Note: crossposting from [my issue on FAB's repo](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/1654)

Comment: I don't use FAB so this is just a suggestion that may or may not work, but have you tried deleting the initial database tables that FAB creates? If you delete the tables and then run `flask db migrate` I think the migration will be generated, and from that point on you can use Flask-Migrate to manage your db.

Comment: @Miguel, unfortunately the tables are created automatically by FAB initialisation. The lead developer will add a new config to allow for the standard migration pattern: https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/issues/1654#issuecomment-864117219

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me.

```
$ flask db stamp head # Set current revision in the database to be head
$ flask db migrate
$ flask db upgrade
```